# Crypto Payment Gateway - DB Access Concurrency

Tags: javascript, database, cryptocurrency

I'm trying to setup a fully independent bitcoin payment processor to learn more about payment processing and the bitcoin network in general. Suppose I have a shop for selling electronics. When a user wants to buy a product my web backend creates an order object, stores it in some database (Redis, MySQL, MongoDB...). This object contains some general product information and a generated BTC address.

Another application, I preferably want to code in NodeJS, is periodically fetching objects from the *same* database periodically over a defined time interval. It processes the payment and if the addresses balance matches the product price it should remove the current order from the database and call a webserver endpoint for handling successful payments.

My question is, is it safe to have two processes accessing the same database? The web backend is only writing to the DB, while my payment processor is reading and writing from/to it.

If not, could I possibly use mutexes or is there a better way for handling payments without using a public API?

Answer (score 0):

You need row level locking on your database, row level means accessing one record, when you lock it only the program that locked it can modify it. You have to do your programming to accommodate the possibilities that 2 processes could be trying to do the same thing at the same time. Take for example : invoicing , if process A creates invoice number 10000 and process B create another invoice with same number then your are in trouble. Solution : you do a maximum of processing , take items , how many , delivery address, etc and only at the very end of the process you lock and obtain an invoice number and release your lock.